# Display problem in a table that contains an object with an array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays

I have a problem with an object containing an array in its view on a table. I want where I have an array in the column. It will split it.
For example

```
itemsToSend = "Orders": [
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": "2022-06-09"
      },
      "OrderNumber": "333333",
      "City": "xxxxxx",
      "Address": "yyyyyyy",
      "Phone": "6666666",
      "Name": "xxxxxx",
      "Trackingnumber": "1",
      "ZipCode": 00000,
      "Province": "xxxx",
      "Quantity": [
        2,
        1
      ],
      "Product_Name": [
        "Nine pants 1",
        "Nine pants 2"
      ],
      "SKU": [
        "CJNSXZHL",
        "CJNS"
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62a1fc431d9acc4a65df50e1"
      }
    },
    {
      "date": {
        "$date": "2022-06-09"
      },
      "OrderNumber": "7488404",
      "City": "Colorad",
      "Address": " xxx",
      "Phone": "3232323",
      "Name": "xxxxxx",
      "Trackingnumber": "1",
      "ZipCode": ooooo,
      "Province": "yyyyy",
      "Quantity": [
        1
      ],
      "Product_Name": [
        "Feet harem pants "
      ],
      "SKU": [
        "CJNSXZHL"
      ],
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "62a1fc431d9acc4a65df50e3"
      }
    }
]
```

Now I do to the object map And sends it by props

```
<>
            {itemsToSends.map((itemsToSend,i)=>(
                <Posreturn key ={i} post={itemsToSend}
                />
```

```
<tr>        
                        <td>{post.OrderNumber}</td>                        
                        <td>{post.Name }</td>
                        <td>{post.SKU}</td>
                        <td>{post.Phone}</td>
                        <td>{post.Address}</td>
                        <td>{post.Country}</td>
                        <td>{post.Province}</td>
                        <td>{post.ZipCode}</td>
                        <td>{post.Quantity}</td>
          </tr>
```

You can see in the first array there is in Quantity, there is an array
And when I display it in the table, I get it in one unsplit cell. Is there any way to split the cell by array

I added a screenshot of what I get
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PfslT.png)
You can see that the first line is incorrect
Both in SKU and in quantity

Thanks for the helpers

Comment: unsplit cell ?  what does that mean can you post screenshot ?

Comment: Agree with @AmanSadhwani, it is not clear what are you expecting. A mock-up would be helpful.

Comment: I added I hope it's more understandable now